# I installed debian and got into GNU GRUB, Need help booting

Tags: boot, grub2, debian-installer

I installed debain got into grub. The installation was perfect, at last it told me to restart. I restarted and the got into GNU GRUB. I have reinstalled debian 10 times now. I need help in booting using The GNU GRUB.

Edit: Here is the photo of the screen.[image]

EDIT 2: As asked, here is the screen of efibootmgr -v

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* debian    HD(1,GPT,18215531-3da9-4e9f-9bd8-fb811a4a8e0b,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi)
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,18215531-3da9-4e9f-9bd8-fb811a4a8e0b,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
```

Comment: When you boot the machine, it stops in GRUB without continuing to boot Linux, right? Does it show you anything on the screen at that point, like an error message or anything else?

Comment: Nope, straight to GRUB

Comment: Welcome, did you have previous installations of OSs? Do you have more than 1 disk? Did you boot from a USB in EFI mode?

Comment: Well I had xubuntu installed, No I only have one disk, well I installed using a USB and the boot mode was in UEFI.

Comment: Did you have a _functional_ installation of Xubuntu previously?

Comment: Yes I did, and I managed to boot using the configfile command, but I need to enter it everytime I login and also, I got another problem, the root password I setup while installing doesn't work in terminal when I use sudo command, it works in the setting menu but it dosent work in terminal, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: If your password includes any special characters, test in the terminal that all those special characters are actually produced by the keystrokes you think will produce them. It might be that the keyboard layout in the terminal is not quite what you expect.

Comment: "_the root password I setup while installing doesn't work in terminal when I use sudo command_" - the `sudo` command (usually) uses the calling user's password, not the target user's password

Answer (score 2):

For your boot problem, the old bootloader from the Xubuntu installation might be still selected as the primary boot target. Go into BIOS boot order settings, and ensure that a boot target named `debian` is in the primary spot.

Alternatively, you can do it from within the OS using the `efibootmgr` command; if you need help there, please copy & paste the output of `efibootmgr -v` (executed as root) to your original post. Once we can see that output, it will be easier for us to confirm the problem and give you the exact commands you'll need to fix it.

In the `efibootmgr -v` output, on the `BootOrder:` line you can see the first boot target is number `0001`, and `Boot0001` is `ubuntu`. So it is a remnant of the previous Ubuntu installation that is giving you trouble. The `BootCurrent:` line also confirms that the system is currently booted using the `Boot0001` boot item.

You can fix it by setting `debian`, i.e. `Boot0000` as the first item in the BootOrder with:

```
efibootmgr -o 0000,0001,2001,2002,2003
```

Or if Xubuntu is no longer in use, you probably should remove the last vestiges of its bootloader:

```
efibootmgr -b 0001 -B
rm -r /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu
```

Comment: I added the screen.

Comment: Just as I expected. The Xubuntu bootloader is still first in the boot order, and since the filesystem that contained its `/boot` directory no longer exists, Xubuntu's GRUB can no longer find its configuration. See my edit above.